# How can I render vectorized text in a PDF using iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

Someone sent me a PDF where the text is not rasterized/scanned, nor is it text, it's just a bunch of vector paths. I believe it happened when someone did a "print to PDF" without embedding the fonts. I'm trying to create raster images of each page so I can send them to OCR.

I'm using iText 7 (latest) under .NET 7. While I'd prefer to use `Leptonica`, the code I've cobbled together below uses `System.Drawing`.

The majority of the code is a custom `IEventListener`:

```
public class VectorShapeProcessor : IEventListener {
    private readonly Bitmap _bitmap;
    private readonly float _scaleX;
    private readonly float _scaleY;
    private readonly Graphics _graphics;
    private readonly IAddsMessage? _log;
    private Matrix? _matrix;

    public VectorShapeProcessor(Bitmap bitmap, IAddsMessage? log) {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
        _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        _scaleX = 300f / 72f;
        _scaleY = 300f / 72f;
        _graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        _log = log;
    }

    private PointF GetMappedPoint(iText.Kernel.Geom.Point p) {
        var x = (float)p.GetX();
        var y = (float)p.GetY();
        // Apply the matrix multiplication
        var transformedX = _matrix.Get(0) * x + _matrix.Get(1) * y + _matrix.Get(2);
        var transformedY = _matrix.Get(3) * x + _matrix.Get(4) * y + _matrix.Get(5);
        // Divide by the last element (w) to obtain the transformed coordinates
        var transformedW = _matrix.Get(6) * x + _matrix.Get(7) * y + _matrix.Get(8);
        transformedX /= transformedW;
        transformedY /= transformedW;
        return new PointF(transformedX * _scaleX, _bitmap.Height - (transformedY * _scaleY));
    }

    private static Color? ToColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.Color deviceColor) {
        if (deviceColor is null) return null;
        if (deviceColor is iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb rgbColor) {
            return Color.FromArgb((int)rgbColor.GetColorValue()[0], (int)rgbColor.GetColorValue()[1], (int)rgbColor.GetColorValue()[2]);
        } else if (deviceColor is iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceCmyk cmykColor) {
            var cmykValues = cmykColor.GetColorValue();
            return Color.FromArgb(
                (int)(255 * (1 - cmykValues[0]) * (1 - cmykValues[3])),
                (int)(255 * (1 - cmykValues[1]) * (1 - cmykValues[3])),
                (int)(255 * (1 - cmykValues[2]) * (1 - cmykValues[3]))
            );
        } else if (deviceColor is iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceGray grayColor) {
            var grayValue = (int)(grayColor.GetColorValue()[0] * 255);
            return Color.FromArgb(grayValue, grayValue, grayValue);
        }
        // Return a default color if the color space is not supported
        return Color.Black;
    }

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (data is not PathRenderInfo pathRenderInfo) return;
        var path = pathRenderInfo.GetPath();
        _matrix = pathRenderInfo.GetCtm();
        var gs = pathRenderInfo.GetGraphicsState();
        var strokeColor = ToColor(gs.GetStrokeColor());
        var fillColor = ToColor(gs.GetFillColor());
        var strokeWidth = gs.GetLineWidth();
        foreach (var subpath in path.GetSubpaths()) {
            var graphicsPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            var p = subpath.GetStartPoint();
            foreach (var shape in subpath.GetSegments()) {
                if (shape is Line lineTo) {
                    var points = lineTo.GetBasePoints();
                    graphicsPath.AddLine(GetMappedPoint(points[0]), GetMappedPoint(points[1]));
                } else if (shape is BezierCurve bezierCurveTo) {
                    var points = bezierCurveTo.GetBasePoints();
                    var lastPoint = GetMappedPoint(points[2]);
                    graphicsPath.AddBezier(GetMappedPoint(points[0], GetMappedPoint(points[1], lastPoint, lastPoint);
                } else {
                    _log.AddWarning("Unsupported type " + shape.ToString());
                }
            }
            graphicsPath.FillMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.FillMode.Winding;
            if (fillColor is not null) {
                using var brush = new SolidBrush((Color)fillColor);
                _graphics.FillPath(brush, graphicsPath);
            }
            if (strokeColor is not null && strokeWidth > 0) {
                using var pen = new Pen((Color)strokeColor, strokeWidth);
                _graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
            }
        }
    }
    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents() => new List<EventType>() { EventType.RENDER_PATH };
}
```

This is then called as follows for each page:

```
var dpi = 300; // desired DPI (dots per inch)
var width = (int)(pageSize.GetWidth() * dpi / 72);
var height = (int)(pageSize.GetHeight() * dpi / 72);
var image = new Bitmap(width, height);
var p = new PdfCanvasProcessor(new VectorShapeProcessor(image, progress));
p.ProcessPageContent(page);
```

It is finding the thousands of paths/subpaths on the page and no errors and thrown, but the PDF ends up looking something like this instead of like a standard typewritten page of text:

[image: example output]

As you can see, the page is mostly white, but with a "starburst" pattern coming from the PDF origin (lower left), where there's a square box that looks suspiciously like perhaps what would result from overwriting every vectorized glyph on top of each other.

This suggests I'm somehow messing up the matrix transformations or something else about how these paths should be placed on the Bitmap's coordinate system, but I'm at a loss.

I played with scaling the output more, but just got a bunch of random intersecting lines and curves, nothing that would resemble a letter.

The matrix transformation piece is new. Before, I was just using GetX/GetY and doing a straight scaling and Y origin adjustment. The output wasn't the same, but similar.

Any iText experts out there? I've already tried ChatGPT, it (and searches in general) seems to be completely confused by iText 5 vs. 7 and Java vs. C#.